# How to serve file on website without it being directly accessible via Google?

Tags: pdf, web

I would like to have a website for the purpose of serving PDFs.

I would like to collect advertising revenue from the website by having ads on pages that the user will have to visit before downloading/viewing the PDFs.  I would not want the direct links to the PDFs appearing on Google search results which would allow the user to bypass the pages containing the ads.

How do I serve the PDFs without the direct links to the PDFs appearing on Google?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a `robots.txt` file on the root of your website to tell google what to crawl.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pdfs/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /~bin/
```

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, and I modified it from another example I found online, but you would want something like this:

You could use a link something like this to hide the real location.

```
<A href="file.php?file=somefile.pdf">Link</a>
```

And the file.php file would have something like this:

```
<?php
// Path yo your PDF files
$path = "/var/www/html/domain/files/" ;

if( isset( $_GET['file'] ) && file_exists( $path.$_GET['file'] ) ){

$name = $path . $_GET['file'] ;

  header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

  readfile( $name );
  exit;
}
?>
```

Instead of seeing the real file address, they would see something like:

```
file.php?file=somefile.pdf
```